# Is it mandatory that an iOS app should work with all calendars

Tags: ios, nscalendar

An iOS app that I am working upon has some date based functionalities. It is working when the Calendar is set as Gregorian. But in the device if I change the calendar to anything else (i.e. Japanese or Buddhist), it doesn't work. Probably because I haven't coded to account for it.

But what is the general standard. Is it expected that any date and time based app support all calendar formats, do a large no. of such apps support all calendars or would an app be approved if it does not work with other calendar types. And if it is approved, where should it be specified that the app works only with a certain calendar type so that the user knows about it?

Comment: Sorry, but [StackOverflow is not AppStore Tech Support](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128579/172661). This question is not really programming-related, and Apple is the only one that can actually answer it.

Comment: I just asked a question, 'what is the usual practice'. I am not asking for any official answer. I tried to look around on the net but did not find anything. As you would know, calendar, time zones, etc. are difficult to work with. I was just asking if this is something which programmers normally account for in the iOS environment.

Comment: Actually, you asked if every calendar was required to be supported, about the approval results if they weren't, and where you should inform the user about the limitation. None of those are answerable by anyone here. In addition, questions here should be limited to one question per post; asking multiple questions means that separate people can answer separate questions, and it's impossible to choose a single one to accept as a solution. The link I provided discusses tech/customer support questions, and the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) talks about how to ask questions here. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official requirement from Apple that all calendars should be supported. Use common sense and do what makes sense for your target audience. If your target audience is Western countries (or the entire world except a small population of Japanese/Buddhist people), then just support Gregorian. If your app is designed specifically for Japanese or Far East regions, support those calendars. Do what applies to the 90% case, and don't waste your time optimizing for marginal use cases. I have shipped many apps that leveraged Calendar and NSDate functionality, and I've never supported anything but Gregorian. I've never heard a complaint.

Comment: Thanks Melsam. Helps, that is all that I was looking for. Now, all will I try for now is to account for time zones and not calendars.

Comment: Exactly. Prioritize your features for the 80-90% use case, and don't try to satisfy every potential customer.